# Can web applications start on demand using nginx (like heroku does)

Tags: nginx, heroku, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to build an application server to host multiple applications, but keeping those applications sleeping most of the time and starting them on demand, like heroku router does for free applications.

Does I need to add a proxy application that start the applications or can nginx be configured to handle that in some way?

I thought about adding a node application that start the application on-demand and proxy the request there, but I'm afraid it might add much time as it will need to proxy every request and also I might loose the first request as the application might not be ready to answer that.

I've also thought that I could use the [ngx_http_auth_request module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) to start the application, but I'm not sure if that could work.

The idea is that I don't have a list of all the applications I will have running, as new applications can be installed anytime.

Comment: Please, add a comment when down-voting as it is not clear what is the reason for it?

Comment: another -1, for asking an unrealistic question, failing to provide any clarifications during the bounty period, failing to accept and upvote any answer, all without any reasonable justification

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible by using `nginx` as a reverse proxy and using `systemd` (or any other `inetd`-replacement).

As a strategy, you can assign each application it's own TCP port to listen on when running - and configure `nginx` to route requests to that application.

Then you can configure systemd socket type units on each applications port and configure it to start your application on each request.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html

Comment: This would add a dependency on systemd (or other inetd replacement), the idea was to find an inetd replacement _within_ nginx.

Comment: nginx is very opinionated about performance and keeping a lean core, so it's unlikely you'll see this in official nginx core or modules.

The closest you'll see is FastCGI support as mentioned by @cnst: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html

What's motivating you to handling everything inside nginx? It sounds like the constraints you have right now might lead you down a path of something with less separation of concern and elegance? Just my 2c

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In the comments to the two existing answers, you mention that, (1), you don't actually need this to be production grade, and, (2), an [`inetd`](http://mdoc.su/o/inetd.8)-like solution is exactly what you're looking for, but without having to have an `inetd`/`xinetd`/`systemd` dependency.

Well, I've got news for you — nginx is a production-grade web-server, intended to address [the C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).  An inetd-like solution, where a `CGI` script is spawned for every single request, is as far away from production-grade quality as you can get, and which wouldn't be capable of handling C10K on modest hardware.

It is, therefore, no surprise that nginx does not support the original CGI model (where each request causes a separate copy of the CGI script to be spawned), instead only having support for FastCGI and the like (where a single process is capable of serving more than one request).  If you wish to implement the original old-school non-scalable `/cgi-bin/`-style architecture, you'd certainly have to rely on third-party web-servers or auxiliary utilities of some sort — it'll never work out-of-the-box in nginx, just the same way as `.htaccess` support will never be added to nginx, as both are terribly inefficient and non-scalable.

Answer (score -1):

It basically sounds like you want the core Heroku functionality implemented, and you want it to be reliable, production grade and, presumably, in only a few lines of code.

Well, that's not really how it works!  There's [a lot of things going on behind Heroku](//twitter.com/MembersGetIt/status/923720807829958656); a very significant amount of time is spent to ensure the applications can sleep and wakeup properly, which is all taken care of by a significant codebase in Erlang, a language known for its parallel-friendly paradigm.

Basically, your question sounds more like a software recommendation, and may be offtopic for StackOverflow.  You might want to try something like [Yandex Cocaine](https://tech.yandex.com/cocaine/) for your [PaaS](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocaine_(PaaS)) needs, although I'm not sure if it support the sleep feature you're seeking about.

At the end of the day, you also have to consider what is it that your apps are actually doing when they need to "sleep".  In the old days of Perl and PHP before the time of Facebook, each request from the browser would often cause the server to spawn a separate process to process said request, which was quite inefficient.  The "new" approach is to have the scripts ready at all times, which ensures that a higher number of total requests per script can be served.

It is not very clear what practical needs you can accomplish nowadays by having your apps sleep on damand — if you're running multiple apps on a given system, and most of them aren't doing anything, then they don't necessarily consume any valuable resources — the scheduler would eventually mark their unused memory as eligible for swap, and if they're really idle, they shouldn't be consuming any CPU, either.

Comment: No, I don't need it to be _production grade_ as it doesn't need to handle a million of connections. Also I don't need to scale as heroku does, or manage multiple servers.